# Import Certificates into Keystore

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

I use the following code for extracting the certificate by using the url link using URL class:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.connect();
```

MY question is: I would like to import certificates directly into java KeyStore so I can use it for validation. I found the following code which is PERFECT but it requires the certificate to be already downloaded :( Can someone help me to modify it. In other word, employ my previous code into the following method:

```
KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
trustStore.load(null); //Make an empty store
InputStream fis = /* insert your file path here */; 
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

while (bis.available() > 0) {
    Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
    trustStore.setCertificateEntry("fiddler"+bis.available(), cert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to import certificates directly into java KeyStore so I can use it for validation

Usually, you use a a custom `X509TrustManager` and override `checkServerTrusted`. In `checkServerTrusted`, you can do things like verify the chain is complete back to your trusted root, or pin the server's public key.

By building the logic into your application, you avoid the problems associated with interacting with a Keystore (like the user deleting a needed certificate); and the risk associated with the CA/Browser's (CA/B) model (include hundreds of roots and subordinates and trust them all).

Some say "trust" is what is used when you don't have any security controls to place. In this case, a custom `X509TrustManager` is the control needed, and there's no need to trust others like in the CA/B model.